# "Transform Patterns" doesn't work

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, transform

Following [this explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=178&v=DGsblCMIp1w&feature=emb_title) to scale a pattern down in **Illustrator 2020** doesn't seem to work.

To reproduce: Create a **New Document**, draw a **Shape**, apply a **Fill color**, select a **Graphic style**, right-click the Object, Select **Transform**, then **Scale**, uncheck everything except **Transform Pattern**, chose a value.

Nothing seems to happen. Alternatively it's impossible to click "Transform Pattern" without "Transform Object" becoming ticked automatically (I don't want to scale the object, just the Pattern).

I've been using Illustrator for 20 years now, so it's either a new bug or I'm missing something obvious.

[image]

Comment: The alternate "ticking" of "object" or "pattern" is standard. **One** of those options *must* be ticked. I can't test CC2020... but based on your gif.. it does look broken. (Works as expected in CS6 and CC 2017). If you use the Scale Tool, and hold down the ~ (tilde) key while dragging... will the pattern scale then?

Comment: I don't think it's standard for a box to become ticked when you click another box. The point of using boxes that can be checked is so that they can be checked independently (otherwise they'd use a radio button or a dropdown,,, or explain why the other one gets checked). When I apply a texture to a shape and then select the "Scale" tool, the box around the object disappears and only anchor points appear (left right top and down of the circle). These cannot be dragged.

Comment: The checkbox toggling is how AI has *always* worked. Radio buttons wouldn't work because you *can* have both checked - radio buttons wouldn't allow that. What if you *drag* with the Scale tool and Tilde key depressed?

Comment: [Selecting the Scale tool is enough to make the box around the circle with the handles disappear](https://imgur.com/a/w1SIVeO) . Here's a screencap showing the normal "Selection Tool" box around the object, then the box disappearing when Scale Tool is clicked, allowing only to drag anchor points (non proportionately to the shape obviously) and at the very end dragging an anchor point in Scale Tool mode with tilde key pressed, even more useless.

Comment: Then yes, it appears broken. The Scale Tool with the Tilde key depressed *should* scale the pattern and *not* the object (clicking anchors and the bounding box are irrelevant)

Answer (score 1):

You have applied a Graphic Style (confusingly called Vonster Pattern Styles) rather than a Pattern Fill Swatch- In your gif it looks like you go to Window> Graphic Styles Libraries> Vonster Pattern Styles to make your fill choice- to be able to scale the pattern fill you will need to have a Pattern Fill Swatch chosen from the Swatch Library> Patterns> Decorative> Vonster Patterns

Comment: He's simply using an external library swatch, not a graphic style. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Scott- I think he went to Graphics Styles Libraries (accidentally I would guess) instead of Swatch Libraries- I tried that with same results he is having- it is not scalable- his gif goes fast and is cut off at the bottom but the list it shows of the Graphics Styles Libraries matches the list mine shows- I am fine to be incorrect but I think I am not

Comment: @Kyle Hmmm . . . I just tried the graphic styles vonster pattern, and it seems to scale as expected, the same as an ordinary pattern.  I'm still using Illustrator CC 22.1 (2018) in Windows. Perhaps this is a bug in an older/newer/Mac version of Illustrator?

Comment: @Billy Kerr- very interesting.... I am on a mac  with Illustrator 24.0.3 (2020) and it is exactly the same as the issue asked about here- object will scale but the pattern will not scale separately if the pattern comes from the Graphic Styles Library. The pattern will scale fine if chosen from the Swatch Library- I just opened Illustrator 22.1 (2018) on my mac and it behaves the same- no scaling- I guess it is a mac bug then...

Comment: FYI. it wouldn't be the first time pattern scaling was an issue. Somewhere around CC2014 pattern scaling would vanish/reset if you copied a pattern-filled object to a new file.

Comment: All this is very interesting. Why would Graphic Styles not be scalable but Pattern Fill Swatches would be? Is this why they are different? Does Adobe explain somewhere that Graphic Styles should work like this? Also Vonster Fill Swatches and Vonster Graphic Styles are different designs in my version... (style chosen in my Gif with the dark green background is different in Fill Swatches)

Comment: @micromachine- some furtherance for you- If you make your circle with the graphic styles vonster fill (as you previously did) then open the appearance panel and just highlight the fill which is the pattern (rather than the dark green solid fill) it will scale as you (we) expect- I tried with some other "graphic styles fills" and this seems to be the case across the board for those- in fact, if you select all the fills except the solid color fill in the appearance panel it will scale properly- Illustrator does not seem to like to scale a solid fill color- at least on my mac

Comment: Well that explains it.. if there are *multiple fills* on an object the *pattern fill* has to be selected for the pattern to be scaled. That's not unique to styles or Vonster stuff.

Comment: Well @Scott- that is the correct concise answer- it was fun for me to dig into and try and figure out why this was happening